# free(): invalid next size (normal) & munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gdb, dynamic-memory-allocation

Calling function `enc()` and `dec()` again and again, it throws errors but new encrypted file is created.

If `enc()` is called first and then using the encrypted file, if used in `dec()` shows **Error: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer**

If `enc()` is called and you terminate the program, later run it and use `dec()` on the now encrypted file, it shows **Error: free(): invalid next size (normal)**

```
void enc()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
  char filename1[FILENAME_MAX];
  int i;
  int size;
  int shift;


  printf("Enter filename:");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s",filename1);

  while((fp1 = fopen(filename1, "r")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s\nTry Again\n", filename1);
    printf("Enter filename:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",filename1);
  }


  printf("Enter shift:");
  scanf("%d",&shift);

  const char *prefix = "encrypted_";
  char *filename2;
  filename2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(filename1) + strlen(prefix)+1)); 
  strcpy(filename2, prefix);
  strcat(filename2, filename1);
  if ((fp2 = fopen(filename2, "w")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s\n", filename1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  free(filename2);



  int ch;
  while ((ch = getc(fp1)) != EOF) {
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
      putc(((ch - 'A') + shift) % 26 + 'A', fp2);
    } 
    else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
      putc(((ch - 'a') + shift) % 26 + 'a', fp2);
    } 
    else {
      putc(ch, fp2);
    }
  }
  fclose(fp1);
  fclose(fp2);
}

void dec()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
  char filename1[FILENAME_MAX];
  int i;
  int size;
  int shift;


  printf("Enter filename:");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s",filename1);


  while((fp1 = fopen(filename1, "r")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s\nTry Again\n", filename1);
    printf("Enter filename:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",filename1);
  }

  printf("Enter shift:");
  scanf("%d",&shift);
  shift = 26-(shift%26);

  const char *prefix = "decrypted_";
  char *filename2;
  filename2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(filename1) + strlen(prefix)+1)); 
  strcpy(filename2, prefix);
  strcat(filename2, filename1);
  if ((fp2 = fopen(filename2, "w")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open file %s\n", filename1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  free(filename2);



  int ch;
  while ((ch = getc(fp1)) != EOF) {
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
      putc(((ch - 'A') + shift) % 26 + 'A', fp2);
    } 
    else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
      putc(((ch - 'a') + shift) % 26 + 'a', fp2);
    } 
    else {
      putc(ch, fp2);
    }
  }
  fclose(fp1);
  fclose(fp2);
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Can you give us a clue?  Which line of code is causing the error? If you're expecting us to throw this into an IDE and debug it for you, could you at least give us some sample input and output?

Comment: This is very new to me, so I'll detail it as much as possible. 
Full code link: https://repl.it/@AlcorInf/Project19
2 errors:

1)When you select option 3, encrypt via file, give filename text.txt, it return encrypted_text.txt.
Using the same encrypted_text.txt to decrypt it using option 4, it shows error.
However, it gives the output properly sometimes

2)After encrypting once, it gives encrypted_text.txt file. Terminate the pgm and run it again, decrypting this throws another error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(filename1) + strlen(prefix)+1));
```

you are reserving space for `sizeof(size_t)` and probably calling `malloc(8)`, remove the `sizeof` keyword:

```
filename2 = malloc(strlen(filename1) + strlen(prefix)+1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @David Ranieri

Comment: On Linux (where the OP apparently is running) this (and similar heap corruption bugs) are trivial to find with Valgrind or Address Sanitizer.